# How can I interpret my error when deploying Shiny site

Tags: r, shinyapps

I am having problems re-deploying an app (that is it was published, I made a few changes and am trying to re-publish a slightly different version). I'm pretty sure that the only thing that I've changed is that I am now using the package "gridExtra".  And I've added a few files to download. Everything words when I preview it from inside RStudio.

The error says something about Biobase, which doesn't seem to be a dependency for gridExtra ?

Any help appreciated,

thanks

Below is copied from my deployment log.

```
    ----- Deployment log started at  2019-08-20 10:43:54  -----
Deploy command: 
 rsconnect::deployApp(appDir = "~/Documents/Professional/Brock/Bidochka_Microbiome/shiny3",      appFileManifest = "/var/folders/x8/c40rtd594gvgp_bzrjt0ljmh0000gq/T/6d26-734e-ec61-1402",      account = "metarhiz-microbiome", server = "shinyapps.io",      appName = "shiny3", launch.browser = function(url) {         message("Deployment completed: ", url)     }, lint = FALSE, metadata = list(asMultiple = FALSE, asStatic = FALSE,          ignoredFiles = "app_test.R"), logLevel = "verbose") 

Session information: 
R version 3.5.2 (2018-12-20)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Mojave 10.14

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/lib/libRblas.0.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_CA.UTF-8/en_CA.UTF-8/en_CA.UTF-8/C/en_CA.UTF-8/en_CA.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.5.2   rsconnect_0.8.13
Cookies: 
[1] "None"
GET /v1/applications/810708 361ms
----- Bundle upload started at  2019-08-20 10:43:55  -----
[2019-08-20 10:43:55] Inferring App mode and parameters 
[2019-08-20 10:43:55] Bundling app dir 
[2019-08-20 10:43:55] Generate manifest.json 
[2019-08-20 10:44:09] Writing Rmd index if necessary 
[2019-08-20 10:44:09] Compressing the bundle 
POST /v1/bundles 341ms
[2019-08-20 10:44:12] Starting upload now 
PUT /bundles/application-810708/13f71d8c7013483da51cf7e1d9963c1f.tar.gz?AWSAccessKeyId=ASIA54P7SCTK2OR32UYU&x-amz-acl=bucket-owner-full-control&Expires=1566315852&content-md5=BexAlI0tMQtDQFi9S0LZ%2FQ%3D%3D&x-amz-security-token=AgoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEAoaCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJGMEQCIDzzcqq%2F8vQTzGOTxuTOfVrAZS8skjMfZlu7Gz%2BsDDlAAiBd44JKB69Ctesd4rOut%2FkB0PTJpYsedmHxD5UjKw5fVSrjAwij%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F8BEAAaDDk1NDU1NTU2OTM2NSIMWonJBJmW40ejTRvyKrcDP2hOYnNIPjm5wqfPlfgWZJafWrvWWmrQY2IlSU6DVHITCXMXNf7GsNH7wttsVWh5Hmpkj5Hq2%2Fg%2B8hYEGg147BkzSL8hiwD9XSK7hPguHliPzrZnTjHXyPMB6xk5nfkubIS1xQPNYY4r5BgVTgrsg9x37zxA61qBySptfKtSoj9NFBQtySiWr5yG3MwgZBXvysOuc8RTAJ%2BbHybgK%2B3BcNQeVzdPzDmLGttjrFpBFo%2FiwpOL88ZZPDPMsEsicgpGT8meVJKs1aIKptj1GXp%2FMosK0iw70%2F03DYNFyz8znUzb8jc%2FK3HDTiV%2B5KwA1tkcl7QP%2BXxCDDRDiokJAejGVR0UTOlZM2qnMWXB6GbnXDChNjDJ4GgUv7%2BBhBnoqmCJyQLTOe7sq8Rh1qJEJTUmeZI6QhhG9NMW5xB%2FWaN5QjY2DsCIdMVRXkyaPSNGoyF%2ByqE5gAi7GeedM1HkmkfkF5WutfhukgIezhT1oZbLenp9B1er2JixXtft1w3HVuIA%2F%2Fsw0wT1aaCTp... <truncated>
[2019-08-20 10:57:19] Upload complete 
POST /v1/bundles/2337837/status 403ms
GET /v1/bundles/2337837 277ms
[2019-08-20 10:57:20] Saving deployment record for shiny3 -  
----- Server deployment started at  2019-08-20 10:57:20  -----
POST /v1/applications/810708/deploy 422ms
Waiting for task: 640236284
GET /v1/tasks/640236284 271ms
GET /v1/tasks/640236284 273ms
  building: Parsing manifest
GET /v1/tasks/640236284 322ms
GET /v1/tasks/640236284 291ms
GET /v1/tasks/640236284 372ms
################################ Begin Task Log ################################ 
GET /v1/tasks/640236284/logs/ 459ms
GET /v1/tasks/?filter=account_id:133495&filter=parent_id:640236284&count=100&offset=0 296ms
GET /v1/tasks/640236289/logs/ 360ms
GET /v1/tasks/?filter=account_id:133495&filter=parent_id:640236289&count=100&offset=0 269ms
################################# End Task Log ################################# 
----- Deployment error -----
Error: Unhandled Exception: Child Task 640236289 failed: Error parsing manifest: Unable to determine package source for Bioconductor package Biobase: Repository must be specified

----- Error stack trace -----
3: stop(status$error, call. = FALSE)
2: client$waitForTask(taskId, quiet)
1: rsconnect::deployApp(appDir = "~/Documents/Professional/Brock/Bidochka_Microbiome/shiny3", 
       appFileManifest = "/var/folders/x8/c40rtd594gvgp_bzrjt0ljmh0000gq/T/6d26-734e-ec61-1402", 
       account = "metarhiz-microbiome", server = "shinyapps.io", 
       appName = "shiny3", launch.browser = function(url) {
           message("Deployment completed: ", url)
       }, lint = FALSE, metadata = list(asMultiple = FALSE, asStatic = FALSE, 
           ignoredFiles = "app_test.R"), logLevel = "verbose")
Error: Unhandled Exception: Child Task 640236289 failed: Error parsing manifest: Unable to determine package source for Bioconductor package Biobase: Repository must be specified
Execution halted
```

Comment: the problem around Bioconductor and a version mismatch between a package's requirments and the version in listed for rsconnect. Here is a [discussion of one person's solution](https://community.rstudio.com/t/http-599-time-out-error-while-deployapp-with-package-mzr/20644/2), looks they resolved it by using the R code `setRepositories(addURLs = c(BioC = "https://bioconductor.org/packages/3.8/bioc"))`

Comment: I added that line in my "app.R", but I still get the same error, but now complaining about a different Bioconductor package that I don't use.  I con't see why bioconductor needs to be involved, can't we do everything via CRAN.

Comment: I'm not sure why Bioconductor is getting involved, What happens if you delete the `rsconnect` directory and re-publish the app?

Comment: tried that and it didn't work

Comment: Sorry mate, I don't have any other things to try other than trying it on my machine. Do you have you code published in a public repo?